# How to force width and height of an image in the pagelayout?

Tags: page-layout

I have created a custom pagelayout. Inside this pagelayout I have a imagefield. Is it possible to set a fixed width and height?

```
<PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel ID="EditModePanel4" runat="server" PageDisplayMode="Display">
                    <div class="article-content">
                        <div class="newsArticleImage" style="float:right;padding:5px;">
                            <PublishingWebControls:RichImageField ID="newsArticleImage" runat="server" FieldName="PublishingRollupImage" />
                        </div>
                        <PublishingWebControls:RichHtmlField FieldName="PublishingPageContent" HasInitialFocus="True" runat="server"/>
                    </div>
                </PublishingWebControls:EditModePanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add rendition id (id value is visible on http://SITE/_layouts/15/ImageRenditionSettings.aspx) `RenditionId="1"` to `RichImageField`

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField ID="newsArticleImage" runat="server" FieldName="PublishingRollupImage" RenditionId="1"/>
```

OR

add display width and display height  to `RichImageField`

`DisplayWidth="500"` and `DisplayHeight="500"` (500 is 500px just for example)

```
<PublishingWebControls:RichImageField ID="newsArticleImage" runat="server" FieldName="PublishingRollupImage" DisplayWidth="500" DisplayHeight="500"/>
```

More on msdn

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richimagefield.displaywidth.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richimagefield.displayheight.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.webcontrols.richimagefield_members.aspx

Comment: DisplayWidth="500" and DisplayHeight="500" works

Answer (score 0):

```
 .yourClass {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
 }
```

I recall from some years ago **CssClass="yourClass"** on the RichImageField had some issues.

You can also target the IMG with a CSS selector

```
 .newsArticleImage > IMG {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
 }
```

Note that your (not-required) ID="newsArticleImage" gives all the Images the same ID